# Active Directory - How do you generate a DirSync cookie without crawling to completion?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

My use case: I need to keep a current index of my multi-domain Active Directory.

I have used an LDAP query with the LDAP paging extension to efficiently fetch all `objectClass=group` and `objectClass=user` objects from Active Directory.

Now, each day, I want to use DirSync to get all changes made to the AD instance that day.

> DirSync is described at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/891995/how-to-poll-for-object-attribute-changes-in-active-directory-on-window

DirSync works by returning a "Cookie" that can resume where your last query left off. It will return all adds, updates and deletes made since.

But I don't get how to get a "Cookie" object representing all changes starting as of the current time...

The only way I can figure out how is by doing an LDAP query and paging all the way until it returns 0 results.

Does anyone know how to generate the Cookie for "current timestamp" or some equivalent way of doing this?

Comment: It might be useful to go back to first principles and think about your AD filter. What users and groups do you actually need? Do you need all the service and shared mailbox accounts, and all the built-in or distribution groups? For one suggestion, a more efficient way to search for normal user accounts is `(samAccountType=805306368)`. If your "real" users have email addresses or an employee ID, try something like `(&(samAccountType=805306368)(mail=*@domain.com))` If all the users/groups you care about are in one OU, constrain your search to that.

Comment: OK I tried that. On my test environment it isn't too slow. But on my production environment, I get to record 500,000 or so then it just hangs and times out after waiting 50 seconds. Am I just missing some simple way to generate the cookie for the current timestamp? I really don't want to use DirSync to go back over all the old changes. I just want to use it daily to get the latest changes for that given day.

Comment: I elaborated my question a bit. Maybe there's no way to do this.

Comment: I meant to refine your LDAP filter to capture the actual users you want. Like, do you have service accounts? Do you need to capture them for whatever it is you're doing? If not, then craft your filter to exclude them. You could also use the `whenChanged` attribute as part of your filter to only return objects changed in the last day. You should always page the LDAP query if it's going to return more than 1000 objects.

Comment: Hi @Trix i elaborated my question more. The whole reason I'm trying to do this i the first place is because I cannot trust that `whenChanged` is an indexed attribute in Active Directory. Right now when I try to use that, the ldap query will do a full scan and will never complete.

Comment: Thanks @Trix for the attention on this. It does help a lot.